# IndexError: list index out of range on opening pickled file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting `'IndexError: list index out of range'` error while un-pickling a data file which I pickled in another program. I am using Python 3.5.2 and Tensorflow v1.0. Below is the code.

Pickling code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = create_feature_sets_and_labels('pos.txt', 'neg.txt')
with open('sentiment_set.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y], f)
```

Un-pickling code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle
with open("sentiment_set.pickle", "rb") as f:
    train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = pickle.load(f)
size = len(train_x[0])
print(size)
```

Output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "4_sentiment_neural_network.py", line 11, in <module>
size = len(train_x[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Even if I try to print out train_x[0], using below code, I still get the exact same error.

```
size = list(train_x[0])
print(size)
```

I don't understand this, what is the error and how to correct it?

Comment: Which line gets the error? Can you post the stack trace? If its at `size = len(train_x[0])` then print train_x to see if its what you think it should be.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it. I have added the stack trace and the error I got after doing what you said. I got exact same error after I tried to print the train_x[0].

Comment: That means it's an empty list. Now you have to figure out why it's empty.